# Получение ответа на запрос JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, https, request

Отправляю на node.js запрос ( отправка формы ) , в ответ я получаю обычный HTML. Так вот , как понять что я отправил удачно форму , или как получить какой то ответ относительно моего запроса чтобы понять хоть что то ? Парсить HTML ?
Но если отправить этот же запрос через браузер - то во вкладке Network -> Response можно увидеть следующий ответ 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я могу получить такой же ответ на запрос не через браузер ?
в объекте response ничего не нашёл интересного

Comment: Смотрите http-заголовки и повторяйте их в своём коде

Comment: что есть node.js в вашей ситуации? ваш собственный экспресс сервер? тогда хттп-заголовки должны помочь

Comment: я использую библиотеку request - https://github.com/request/request
Попробую использовать заголовки , можете подсказать что можно почитать о них чтобы понять на что влияют заголовки ?

Comment: Добавьте код сервера и формы

Answer (score 0):

Тестировать серверный скрипт легче всего через командную строку cURL.
Тестировать клиентский скрипт проще всего через серввис http://httpbin.org.
Этот сервис с открытым исходным кодом и может быть поднят на вашем сервере.
Также в изучении ненормального поведения и клиентского и серверного скриптов помогает HAR.